# TFS 2013 - bug not an option to add in backlog but using scrum template

Tags: tfs

I'm using the Scrum template in TFS 2013 and as far as I understand, on the backlog page under New, I should be able to choose between adding a Product Backlog Item or a Bug. There is no drop-down, only an option to add a Product Backlog Item.

Why is there no option to add a Bug here?

Added info: I'm using tfs 2013.4. Also I tried to export my processconfig but I don't know if I did it correctly. This is what is in my processconfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectProcessConfiguration>
  <FeedbackRequestWorkItems category="Microsoft.FeedbackRequestCategory" pluralName="Feedback Requests" singularName="Feedback Request">
    <States>
      <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
    </States>
  </FeedbackRequestWorkItems>
  <FeedbackResponseWorkItems category="Microsoft.FeedbackResponseCategory" pluralName="Feedback Responses" singularName="Feedback Response">
    <States>
      <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
    </States>
  </FeedbackResponseWorkItems>
  <PortfolioBacklogs>
    <PortfolioBacklog category="Microsoft.FeatureCategory" pluralName="Features" singularName="Feature">
      <AddPanel>
        <Fields>
          <Field refname="System.Title" />
        </Fields>
      </AddPanel>
      <Columns>
        <Column width="100" refname="System.WorkItemType" />
        <Column width="400" refname="System.Title" />
        <Column width="100" refname="System.State" />
        <Column width="50" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BusinessValue" />
        <Column width="100" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.TargetDate" />
        <Column width="200" refname="System.Tags" />
      </Columns>
      <States>
        <State type="Proposed" value="New" />
        <State type="InProgress" value="In Progress" />
        <State type="Complete" value="Done" />
      </States>
    </PortfolioBacklog>
  </PortfolioBacklogs>
  <RequirementBacklog category="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" parent="Microsoft.FeatureCategory" pluralName="Backlog items" singularName="Backlog item">
    <AddPanel>
      <Fields>
        <Field refname="System.Title" />
      </Fields>
    </AddPanel>
    <Columns>
      <Column width="100" refname="System.WorkItemType" />
      <Column width="400" refname="System.Title" />
      <Column width="100" refname="System.State" />
      <Column width="50" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort" />
      <Column width="200" refname="System.IterationPath" />
      <Column width="200" refname="System.Tags" />
    </Columns>
    <States>
      <State type="Proposed" value="New" />
      <State type="Proposed" value="Approved" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="Committed" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Done" />
    </States>
  </RequirementBacklog>
  <TaskBacklog category="Microsoft.TaskCategory" parent="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" pluralName="Tasks" singularName="Task">
    <AddPanel>
      <Fields>
        <Field refname="System.Title" />
      </Fields>
    </AddPanel>
    <Columns>
      <Column width="400" refname="System.Title" />
      <Column width="100" refname="System.State" />
      <Column width="100" refname="System.AssignedTo" />
      <Column width="50" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" />
    </Columns>
    <States>
      <State type="Proposed" value="To Do" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="In Progress" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="Done" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
    </States>
  </TaskBacklog>
  <TypeFields>
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity" type="Activity" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority" type="Order" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Feedback.ApplicationLaunchInstructions" type="ApplicationLaunchInstructions" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Feedback.ApplicationStartInformation" type="ApplicationStartInformation" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Feedback.ApplicationType" type="ApplicationType">
      <TypeFieldValues>
        <TypeFieldValue type="ClientApp" value="Client application" />
        <TypeFieldValue type="RemoteMachine" value="Remote machine" />
        <TypeFieldValue type="WebApp" value="Web application" />
      </TypeFieldValues>
    </TypeField>
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort" type="Effort" />
    <TypeField format="{0} h" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" type="RemainingWork" />
    <TypeField refname="System.AreaPath" type="Team" />
  </TypeFields>
  <Weekends>
    <DayOfWeek>Sunday</DayOfWeek>
    <DayOfWeek>Saturday</DayOfWeek>
  </Weekends>
  <WorkItemColors>
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFCC293D" secondary="FFFAEAE5" name="Bug" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Code Review Request" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Code Review Response" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FF773B93" secondary="FFEEE2F2" name="Feature" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Feedback Request" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Feedback Response" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Impediment" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FF009CCC" secondary="FFD6ECF2" name="Product Backlog Item" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Shared Steps" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFF2CB1D" secondary="FFF6F5D2" name="Task" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Test Case" />
  </WorkItemColors>
</ProjectProcessConfiguration>
```

Here is my categories.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cat:CATEGORIES xmlns:cat="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/workitemtracking/categories">
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.BugCategory" name="Bug Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Bug" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.CodeReviewRequestCategory" name="Code Review Request Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Code Review Request" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.CodeReviewResponseCategory" name="Code Review Response Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Code Review Response" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.FeatureCategory" name="Feature Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Feature" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.FeedbackRequestCategory" name="Feedback Request Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Feedback Request" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.FeedbackResponseCategory" name="Feedback Response Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Feedback Response" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.HiddenCategory" name="Hidden Types Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Code Review Request" />
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="Code Review Response" />
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="Feedback Request" />
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="Feedback Response" />
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="Shared Steps" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" name="Requirement Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Product Backlog Item" />
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="Bug" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.SharedStepCategory" name="Shared Step Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Shared Steps" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.TaskCategory" name="Task Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Task" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.TestCaseCategory" name="Test Case Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Test Case" />
  </CATEGORY>
</cat:CATEGORIES>
```

Comment: There sure should be. Which exact version of TFS 2013? Update 1, 2 ,3, 4 or 5? Can you export your processconfig and add it to the question (edit the question to add the additional information?) -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500413.aspx

Comment: If you're running TFS 2013 update 4 or later, there is a configurable option in the team's backlog settings which governs whether bugs are shown on the backlog or not: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj920163%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

Comment: @jessehouwing The link https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj920163%28v=vs.120%29.aspx seems to be only for Agile or CMMI templates. If I go to the settings I see the checkbox but it is disabled and it says "TF400917: The current configuration is not valid for this feature. This feature cannot be used until you correct the configuration."

Comment: @orange_board05 The link you posted has instructions for what you need to do to your process template to enable the option. It's not for just Agile or CMMI process templates.

Comment: So at least that isn't it. I was trying to exclude possibilities. Your process config looks good. Only thing that can now be wrong is your categories.xml, where bug would no longer be in the requirements category...

Comment: @jessehouwing The WIT definitions could also be missing required fields

Comment: @Daniel, yes that's true.

Comment: @jessehouwing I just posted my categories.xml. Bug isn't under the requirements category, so I added <WORKITEMTYPE name="Bug"> under Requirement Category and now get the following statement when trying to go to the backlog: "The following element contains an error: RequirementBacklog/States. TF400536: This element defines the states for work items that appear on your backlog. The initial state value for each work item type must match one of the states defined in this element. The following work item types have an initial state that is not included in the defined states: 'Bug'."

Comment: In my processconfig.xml I added two states under <RequirementBacklog category="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" parent="Microsoft.FeatureCategory" pluralName="Backlog items" singularName="Backlog item"> -------------------       <State type="Proposed" value="To Do" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="In Progress" /> I think this may have fixed it - I now get a dropdown to choose between a product backlog item and a bug when on the backlog page!

Comment: I think this may mean that a bug marked as "done" is considered Complete whereas I would have expected it to be still "Inprogress", but I guess if I'm looking at bugs the same way as pbi's then maybe that is the intended behaviour.